# Nested Iterator on ArrayList<Integer> removes values from both lists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have two nested Iterators for ArrayLists which contain Integer. 
When both have the same value and I want to remove this value from only one of the lists, it removes them from both. The lists contain values 1-5, and after this iteration, both contain 2-5, though I want the second list to stay the same:

```
public static boolean revise(ArrayList<Value> arc) {
    Value node1 = arc.get(1);
    Value node2 = arc.get(0);
    boolean delete = false;

    loop:
    for (Iterator<Integer> iterator1 = node1.getValues().iterator(); iterator1.hasNext(); ) {
        Integer i = iterator1.next();

        for (Iterator<Integer> iterator2 = node2.getValues().iterator(); iterator2.hasNext(); ) {
            Integer j = iterator2.next();

            if (i == j) {
                iterator1.remove();
                delete = true;
                continue loop;
            }

        }
    }
    return delete;
}
```

Edit:
This is what my Value class looks like:

```
public class Value {

private ArrayList<Integer> values;
private String name;

public Value(String name, ArrayList<Integer> values) {
    this.name = name;
    this.values = values;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getValues() {
    return values;
}

public String toString(){
    return (name + values.toString());
}
}
```

This is how the nodes are created:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

//land
public static Value brite = new Value("Brite", numbers);
public static Value norweger = new Value("Norweger", numbers);
```

arc is an ArrayList of two Values each.

Comment: How are `node1` and `node2` created and populated, and could you show the `Value` class ?

Comment: Try doing the same with two barebones lists -- I have the feeling it has something to do with your two `Value` objects pointing to the same list.

Comment: Take a defensive copy of `values` in the constructor of `Value`. You're reusing the same list.

Comment: @AndyTurner could you explain what you mean by defensive copy?

Comment: defensive copy of values or numbers will do.. because here you are iterating over same numbers object which is common to both brite and norweger.

Comment: @alena `this.values = new ArrayList<>(values);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `brite` and `norweger` have the same list.

You either Use **List.clone()** when you're creating values:

```
public static Value brite = new Value("Brite", numbers.clone());
public static Value norweger = new Value("Norweger", numbers.clone());
```

Or you create two different lists:

```
public static Value brite = new Value("Brite", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
public static Value norweger = new Value("Norweger", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 6, 7)));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try below you will understand what is wrong.

```
    public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    public static ArrayList<Integer> numbers2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    //land
    public static Value brite = new Value("Brite", numbers);
    public static Value norweger = new Value("Norweger", numbers2 );
```

Take different numbers object. According to your current code both iterators are actually working over the same numbers object!